# What is the domain of continued fraction?

Tags: number-theory, definition

I'm trying to formally define (generalized) continued fraction.

Consider $[i;\sqrt2,i,i]$.

This is not well defined since $i+\frac{1}{i}=0$.

What would be a domain of continued fraction? (As a function)

That is, how do I formally define continued fraction?

EDIT:

I have searched for it, and it's on wikipedia that continued fraction can be defined by using Möbius transformation.

Since I'm familiar with Möbius transformation, I see this definition is perfectly formal. Is this the standard definition? If not, what is the standard definition?

Comment: Is $i$ the imaginary unit here?

Comment: Who told you that $1+\frac1i=0$? They're lying.

Comment: For the standard applications to number theory the numbers in a continued fraction should be positive integers (possibly except the first one).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Edited

Comment: I think that OP meant that $i + \frac1i=0$. {The tail end of his c.f.)